# Django, MySQL tests create all tables, but why is each table empty?

Tags: python, mysql, django

**Problem Statement:**

- When I use any test case that tries a db lookup I get a typical db error like "matching query does not exist."
- I cannot figure out why test db creation creates the tables, but fails to put the data into the tables.
- Using MySQL db in development works fine.

**So Far:**

1. Performed significant amounts of searching for similar issues posted by others, but failed to find any
2. I used --keepdb and found that all tables successfully create, however, they are all empty; even tables like auth_user.

**Work around:**
I can manually add data to the test tables and reach a successful test case with a db query (yay!), however, it is a super pain and not easily repeatable (or sustainable).

===========================
**Notes:**

- Migrations are regularly deleted from django_migrations table and the migrations directory with subsequent make and fake. The standalone migration file; 0001_initial.py looks good.
- Using typical database settings, no test db defined, no mirrors.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '***',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior in tests. You can use fixtures to fill data in the test database,  I believe keepdb doesn't keep the data b/w test cases only keeps the schema. You can create some functions which then can be reused/duplicated in for each app's  test case.

Comment: Can also use django loaddata commad to fill data in the test db

Comment: Thanks @Jisson! you got me on the right track. What I missed was that there are 2 kinds of migrations, 1) Schema Migrations and 2) _Data_ Migrations. I assumed that Django would just automatically load the data. Looks like I have some more work to do... Here is the reference to Data Migrations for anyone who hits the same snag in the future: [Data Migrations] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)